# How can I change title and URL in script by clicking on post?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I use WordPress and want to click on post in archive page change on script.

```html
    <a href="link1" id="shareBtn"> title1 </a>
    <a href="link2" id="shareBtn"> title2 </a>
    <a href="link3" id="shareBtn"> title3 </a>
    <a href="link4" id="shareBtn"> title4 </a>
    <a href="link5" id="shareBtn"> title5 </a>
```

I want when click at links change script source.

```js
  <script>
            document.querySelector('#shareBtn')
            .addEventListener('click', event => {
      
                if (navigator.share) {
                    navigator.share({
     
                     
                        // web share dialog
     //change this title
 title: 'GeeksForGeeks',
     
                   
     //change this url
  url: 'https://geeksforgeeks.org'


                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log('Thanks for sharing!');
                    }).catch(err => {
     
                        // Handle errors, if occurred
                        console.log(
                        "Error while using Web share API:");
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                } else {
     
                    // Alerts user if API not available 
                    alert("Browser doesn't support this API !");
                }
            })
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have same ID for multiple elements. After having different id for each, you may try this:

```js
function share(linkId) {
    const linkElement = document.getElementById(linkId);

    if (navigator.share) {
        navigator.share({
            title: linkElement.textContent,
            url: linkElement.href
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Thanks for sharing!');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error while using Web share API:");
            console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Browser doesn't support this API!");
    }
}

document.getElementById('shareBtn1').addEventListener('click', () => share('shareBtn1'));
document.getElementById('shareBtn2').addEventListener('click', () => share('shareBtn2'));
document.getElementById('shareBtn3').addEventListener('click', () => share('shareBtn3'));
document.getElementById('shareBtn4').addEventListener('click', () => share('shareBtn4'));
document.getElementById('shareBtn5').addEventListener('click', () => share('shareBtn5'));
```